# probability of empty box

Tags: probability, combinations

> Each of 10 balls (numbered from 1 to 10) is placed into one of 10 boxes (numbered from 1 to 10). What is the probability that exactly box of number 1 and box of number 10 are empty?

I think If there are 2 empty boxes, so there are 2 boxes with 2 balls;
(n-4)! ways to arrange (n-4) balls to put in exactly (n−4) holes.

It's have $$n\choose 2$$ choices for the empty box

$$n-1 \choose 2$$ choices left for the boxes with 2 balls

result:
$$\frac{{n-1\choose 2}{n\choose 2} (n-4)! }{n^n}$$
Is this correct?

Comment: Does what I edit reflect your intention? Feel free to roll it back if it doesn't!

Comment: There could be a box with three balls.

Comment: For choosing $2$ out of $n$, please write it as $n \choose 2$ or $nC2$.

Comment: Isn't this just $\frac{8^{10}}{10^{10}}$?

Comment: @JohnDouma that depends on interpretation.  In the interpretation of the OP and Henry, we wanted boxes $1$ and $10$ to be empty and for these to be the *only* boxes that are empty.  In the answer of $8^{10}/10^{10}$ that is where boxes $1$ and $10$ *and possibly others* are empty.

Comment: @JohnDouma $8^{10}$ does not ensure that all $8$ boxes have balls

Comment: @MathLover I see what you mean. If box 2 was empty then there would be three empty boxes. I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: You can use stars and bars for the eight possibilities and then divide by all possibilities.

Comment: @JohnDouma No!  Stars and bars are rarely ever useful in probability contexts.  It is heavily implied that the random process involved in distributing these balls into the bins is to one at a time take a ball and independently and uniformly put it into one of the available bins.  The outcomes described by stars-and-bars are not equally likely to occur.

Comment: Yeah, stars and bars won’t work. @JohnDouma The possibilities are not equally likely.

Answer (score 2):

There are two cases -

$1$) two boxes have two balls each

$2$) one of the boxes has three balls.

Number of arrangements are -

case $1$: $ \displaystyle {8 \choose 2}{10 \choose 4} {4 \choose 2} \cdot6!$

which is we select $2$ boxes out of $8$ for $2$ balls each (as $1$ and $10$ are empty), choose $4$ balls that will go into those two selected boxes and then arrange $2$ balls each in those two boxes. Finally arrange $6$ remaining balls in $6$ boxes.

case $2$: $ \displaystyle {8 \choose 1}{10 \choose 3}  \cdot 7!$

The explanation is similar to case $1$.

To find probability, add both cases and divide by $10^{10}$.

Alternatively you can apply Principle of Inclusion Exclusion or [Stirling Number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: If the 2 empty boxes was the box of number 2 and 8,  is the probability equal to the original question?

Comment: @SunnySmith yes it would be same

Comment: @SunnySmith but if the question said that exactly two boxes were empty (and not two specific boxes) then it would be different as any two boxes could be empty then.

Answer (score 2):

The correct (general) answer for the two-boxes-with-two-balls numerator is

$${n-2\choose2}{n\choose2}{n-2\choose2}(n-4)!$$

That is, you first choose which two of the $n-2$ "interior" boxes (i.e., not box $1$ or box $n$, which are to remain empty) will receive two balls, then you pick two of the $n$ balls to go in the first of these, then two of the remaining $n-2$ balls to go into the second, and then distribute the remaining $n-4$ balls into the remaining $n-4$ boxes.

But as Henry observed in a comment, you need to consider the possibility that one box gets *three* balls (and the other "interior" boxes get one each). This gives another

$${n-2\choose1}{n\choose3}(n-3)!$$

possibilities. So the overall probability is

$${\displaystyle{n-2\choose2}{n\choose2}{n-2\choose2}(n-4)!+{n-2\choose1}{n\choose3}(n-3)!\over n^n}$$